# What is change of billing?

Tags: meaning

Below is a diagram from Brian Krebbs, a security researcher, which shows that our email is more valuable than we think.

[image: diagram]

What is change of billing and how this could be dangerous? Does it mean change of billing address or anything else?

Comment: It is not clear.  @phoog gives one scenario, but there are others.  Eg, the crook could alter bills you send out, routing payments to them rather than you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it means change of billing address.  Utility bills, and others, are often accepted as prrof of residence.  An identity thief could use this to help build records of a victim's stolen identity.

It is also dangerous because the identity thief will probably not pay the bills.  This could have a negative impact on the victim's credit rating if the victim doesn't notice in time that bills are missing.

Comment: I thought of a different use of this phrase.  Suppose a new movie came out with Bill Cosby playing a significant role (Brits:  Substitute Jimmy Savile.)  When the original ads were drawn up, Cosby's name figured front and center to attract viewers.  Now, with the scandal, his name is moved to the bottom and very small letters.  This is also a change in billing.

Comment: @StevenLittman that is certainly true.  It's pretty clear from the context that this was not the intended meaning in this case.

Comment: I didn't say it was.

Comment: @StevenLittman that is also true, but you also didn't say it wasn't.